PowerBI calculate column filter
I have a problem, I have two columns in my table fecha_final and fecha_proceso, I need to filter only one of them at the time but in an strange way. I want to create a new column called fecha_final and a parameter table where you can choose date you want to use to filter. I create the new column like this
FechaFinalFiltrada = 
IF(
    SELECTEDVALUE(FechaSeleccionada[Parameter Fields]) = 0, 
    SELECTEDVALUE(Avances_TC[fecha_proceso]), 
    SELECTEDVALUE(Avances_TC[fecha_transaccion])
)

But created columns are not in the same context as parameters filters, if i change the selected date to filter the column didn't change. I want to know if exist a way to do this or the context filter make it imposible. This is my parameter table:
FechaSeleccionada = {
    ("Fecha Proceso", 0),
    ("Fecha Transccion", 1)
}

I try it with measures, but you cant filter a measure and that is what I want. Filter the date fecha_final but the value depends on the parameter selected in the slicer

could you pls provide some sample data and expected output?
